# Ошибка отображения элемента \u232B

Tags: java, android, unicode, android-button

Есть кнопка, вместо текста код отображения символа `\u232B` в окне редактора все отображается правильно как показано на скрине, но при запуске приложения кнопка пустая
[image: в редакторе]

[image: при запуске приложения]

Comment: Вообще, я заметил, в андроиде много символов юникода не отображается. Может, проще нарисовать картинку и ставить её на кнопку? Вот, кстати, и ответ по вашему символу http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20078789/unicode-character-u232b-does-not-display-on-button

Comment: ну как бы знаю что можно нарисовать картинку, хотелось бы разобраться в чем пролема

Comment: Этот символ не поддерживается шрифтом.

Comment: Попробуйте скачать здесь https://groups.google.com/group/tamil_ulagam/attach/47953ebb6d9f23d4/TAU_BHON.TTF?part=0.8&authuser=0 шрифт и задать его для view как здесь http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499270/write-comma-separated-unicode-in-android-textview

Comment: @КириллМалышев, не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим способом:
скачал [тут](https://material.io/icons/#ic_backspace) иконку и сменил `Button` на `ImageButton`

```
                <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_C"
                android:tag="C"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp"
                android:paddingLeft="33dp"
                android:paddingRight="33dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_18dp" />
```